# redefining built-in function

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

How would i redefine a built-in function, while
 keeping a reference to the old function under a different name?

ie with SBCL

```
(unlock-package 'common-lisp)
(defun old+ (a b) ??????
(defun + (a b) (old+ a b))
```

I'm porting code to a LISP implementation that doesn't have float data type. So I wanted to redefine the the math ops to use fixed integer math.

I suppose i can solve this problem with search-and-replace as well :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

```
(defconstant +old-plus+ (fdefinition '+))
(defun + (&rest args) (apply +old-plus+ args))
```

Note that if you evaluate this again (e.g., by reloading the file where this code contained), you might have a problem: `+old-plus+` might get silently redefined to your new `+` (or you might get an error, or you might get a warning) and you will lose the original `+` definition.

Therefore it seems that a better approach would be to create a new package where all symbols are imported from `CL` except for `+` which is shadowed, and then use that package instead of `CL` (untested):

```
(rename-package "COMMON-LISP" "COMMON-LISP-ORIGINAL")
(make-package "COMMON-LISP")
(use-package "COMMON-LISP-ORIGINAL" "COMMON-LISP")
(shadow "+" "COMMON-LISP")
(do-external-symbols (s "COMMON-LISP-ORIGINAL")
  (export (find-symbol (symbol-name s)) "COMMON-LISP"))
(defun common-lisp::+ (&rest args) (apply #'common-lisp-original:+ args))
```

Now you should be able to process the code.

Note that you should not load the above code twice because "consequences are undefined" if you [`rename-package`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rn_pkg.htm) to an existing `"COMMON-LISP-ORIGINAL"`.