# Way to redefine builtin function inside a lisp package

Tags: common-lisp, package

I'm currently writing small implementation of vector arithmetics, and I want to define my own «-» and «+» (and maybe other) functions that will operate on vectors.

And I also want to place all these functions in a package.

And I want this hypothetical package, let's say it's called «vec», to behave like this:

- While inside the package, I define functions «-» and «+», but when I *call* + or - (inside the same package), Common Lisp builtins are invoked.
- If previous is not possible, I want to call builtin `+` and `-` as `cl:+` and `cl:-`, but  without necessity of explicitly importing every single other needed function from `:cl`.
- When I import `vec` package, or mention it in `:use` section of definition of another package, common-lisp package's «-» and «+» are still available, and package vec's functions are called like `(vec:+ v1 v2)`, so there is no name conflict between `vec:+` and `cl:+`.

So, what is considered the best (and proper) way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [redefining built-in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691868/redefining-built-in-function)

Comment: You might be interested in the grid subsystem of [Antik](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/antik/), which defines operations for generalized arrays (including foreign arrays). The mathematical and some array operation symbols are shadowed. Look in the file init/package.lisp to see how the shadowing is done.

Comment: @sds, not really. I was interested especially in packages, but it true that answer to that question is also suits my case perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to define a symbol `+` and have it refer to `+` from another package at the same time.

You don't need to import symbols. If they are exported you can use them as `foo:+`. If they are not exported, they can be used as `foo::+`.

There is no point of `using` (in the programmatic sense - sure it makes sense to introduce a package as a namespace for vector operations) a package if you don't want to make symbols accessible in the using package. If you want to write `vec:+`, then there is no point in using the package `VEC`. Just export symbols from `VEC`.

Just for illustration:

```
CL-USER 6 > (defpackage "VEC"
               (:use "CL")
               (:shadow cl:+ cl:-)
               (:export "+" "-"))
#<The VEC package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>

CL-USER 7 > (defun vec:+ (a b) (+ a b))
VEC:+

CL-USER 8 > (defun vec:- (a b) (- a b))
VEC:-

CL-USER 9 > (defpackage "GRAPH" (:use "CL"))
#<The GRAPH package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 10 > (in-package "GRAPH")
#<The GRAPH package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

GRAPH 11 > (defun foo (a b) (+ (vec:+ a b) 42))
FOO
```

Note, if the current package is `VEC`, then `+` refers to `VEC:+`. For the CL `+` you would then need to write `CL:+`.

Always keep in mind:

- packages are resolved at read time.
- the current package determines the default package which is used during read time. changing the current package does not change already read symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much! That `:shadow` thing is exactly what I needed.