# Change default reader in common lisp

Tags: stream, common-lisp, reader, reader-macro

I wrote some function that could replace the function `read` of common lisp

```
(defun my-read (stream &rest args)
  (declare (ignore args))
  (funcall (my-get-macro-character (read-char stream))))
```

Is there a way to use this function as default reader?

Comment: Short answer: no, at least not portably.  Things like `load` or `compile-file` might have the reader inlined, or they might refer to internal reader definitions, e.g. to bypass the optional/key argument handling overhead.

Answer (score 5):

You can't redefine the built in functions<sup>1</sup>, but you can define a package that shadows **cl:read** and defines a new function **my:read**, so that when you use that package, it *looks like* it's the default **read** function.  E.g., something like this:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage #:my-package 
           (:use "COMMON-LISP")
           (:shadow #:read)
           (:export #:read))
;=> #<PACKAGE "MY-PACKAGE">

CL-USER> (defun my-package:read (&rest args)
           (declare (ignore args))
           42)
;=> MY-PACKAGE:READ

CL-USER> (defpackage #:another-package
           (:use #:my-package "COMMON-LISP")
           (:shadowing-import-from #:my-package #:read))
;=> #<PACKAGE "ANOTHER-PACKAGE">

CL-USER> (in-package #:another-package)
;=> #<PACKAGE "ANOTHER-PACKAGE">

ANOTHER-PACKAGE> (read)
;=> 42
```

---

1. Actually, as [Rainer Joswig noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048355/change-default-reader-in-common-lisp/31049015#comment50124956_31049015) in the comments, even though it's undefined behavior (see [11.1.2.1.2 Constraints on the COMMON-LISP Package for Conforming Programs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm)), there often *are* ways to redefine some of the Common Lisp function,  For instance, in SBCL you can use **unlock-package**, as shown in [redefining built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15691868/1281433).  CLISP has [package locks](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/pack-lock.html).  Other implementations may have similar functionality.

Comment: Note that the standard does not allow to redefine standard functions, but many/most actual implementations have an implementation specific way to do so.

Comment: That is not useful to change default reader for reading the main file

Comment: @cl-porky11 I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "the main file".  If you have a definition like this somewhere, then all you'd need to do is `(in-package #:my-package)` at the top of that file.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `set-macro-character` on all "valid" input characters in a readtable. (This is okay if you only accept ASCII input, but I don't know if it would be practical for full Unicode.)

Something like this:

```
(defun replace-default-read-behavior (rt fn)
  (loop for c across 
        " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
        do (set-macro-character c fn t rt)))

(defun my-parser (stream char)
  (format t "custom read: ~A~A" char (read-line stream)))

(defun my-get-macro-character (char)
  (declare (ignore char))
  #'my-parser)

(defun my-read (stream char)
  (funcall (my-get-macro-character char) stream char))

(defvar *my-readtable* (copy-readtable ()))

(replace-default-read-behavior *my-readtable* #'my-read)

(let ((*readtable* *my-readtable*))
  (read-from-string "foo"))
custom read: foo  ; printed
NIL               ; returned
3
```

Comment: I also thought about this solution, but it won't work for non-standard-characters, what might be a problem in some cases. (you forgot #\Newline in the string)

Comment: @cl-porky11 agreed. Worst case, unexpected characters could cause your program to silently misbehave. If you adjust `my-read` to ingest the entire input you can loosen the requirement to say just the first character of input has to be one you expect. That's still not satisfying, but I don't know of a better way to do it.